欠ける & 要る Intransitive state verbs?
I was watching Initial D and found this sentence:
(Original)
お前には走り屋としての大事なものがぽっかりと欠けている
(Shortened by me)
お前に大事なものが欠けている (let me know if it sounds unnatural)
And my question is, does the に particle act like the context marker for 欠ける since it is an intransitive verb? Basically what I am asking, does the に here show WHO is the one who is lacking something?
And would it apply to a similar sentence like ''要る'' considering it is also intransitive?
''君に車が要る''

Yes, に can attach to 欠けている and marks the person who lacks something. The rule is simple: "AにBが欠けている" means "A lacks B". Similarly, "AにBが要る" means "A needs B" or "B is necessary for A".

However, if you said お前に大事なものが欠けている, it would mean something that's totally different from the original sentence! Compare the following:

お前には大事なものが欠けている。
You lack something important.
[more literally] Regarding you, an important thing is missing.
お前に大事なものが欠けている。
It lacks something that is important to you.

So the meaning of the sentence changes completely depending on whether you use は or not. This is because に can also attach to 大事な. In sentence 2, お前に is right before 大事な, so it will be attached not to 欠けている but to 大事な, resulting in "important thing to you". By adding the topic marker は, you can tell that には is marking the topic of the entire sentence, so it will be attached to the main verb of the sentence, 欠けている.

Ahhhhh I understand now. Thanks for the good replies as always. Now it makes sense.

@HoodIntercooledSubaru — Dunno if this helps: think of 欠ける as an intransitive verb, describing something about the thing that is lacking / is missing.  To rephrase the English translation accordingly, お前には大事なものが欠けている → "an important thing is lacking in you."
